# stuck in POST for an OptiPlex 790 series with no Boot Options

Tags: linux, boot, usb, hardware-failure, post

The `BIOS` shows:

`OptiPlex 790 Series`

`BIOS Revision A11`

the bar is fully across for finishing `POST` but won't proceed.  I've swapped keyboards.  It's fairly newly purchased.  There's only keyboard and mouse.  No sounds or beeps, although I did turn down the volume -- but that was from within the GUI.  Presumably beeps would ignore any OS changes to volume.

Cannot boot.  I'm looking for a live disc, but am alarmed that pressing `F12` doesn't get me into `BIOS` settings.

I'm speculating that it's something to do with boot order?  Not looking to open the [case](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000607.htm) at this point.

If I'm reading the LED lights correctly:

`Power Button Problem Description BIOS may be corrupt or missing. Troubleshooting Steps The computer hardware is operating normally but the BIOS may be corrupt or missing.`

Comment: Disconnect power cord, hold power button in for 15 seconds, plug in and power up, see it you can enter bios now.

Comment: Or see this>>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln300716/how-to-recover-the-bios-on-a-dell-computer-or-tablet?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

If BIOS corruption happens spontaneously to a "fairly newly purchased" computer,
don't bother trying to fix it through software, as
this problem is most likely caused by hardware.

Return the computer if it can be reimbursed.
Otherwise ask for an exchange or at least for Support repairs.